# How do I parse "YYYY-MM-DD" with joda time

Tags: date, jodatime

I'm trying to use joda-time to parse a date string of the form `YYYY-MM-DD`.  I have test code like this:

```
DateTimeFormatter dateDecoder = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("YYYY-MM-DD");
DateTime dateTime = dateDecoder.parseDateTime("2005-07-30");

System.out.println(dateTime);
```

Which outputs:

```
2005-01-30T00:00:00.000Z
```

As you can see, the `DateTime` object produced is `30 Jan 2005`, instead of `30 July 2005`.

Appreciate any help.  I just assumed this would work because it's one of the date formats listed [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime).

Answer (score 5):

The confusion is with what the ISO format actually is. `YYYY-MM-DD` is not the ISO format, the actual resulting date is.

So `2005-07-30` is *in* ISO-8601 format, and the spec uses `YYYY-MM-DD` to *describe* the format. There is no connection between the use of `YYYY-MM-DD` as a pattern in the spec and any piece of code. The only constraint the spec places is that the result consists of a 4 digit year folowed by a dash followed by a 2 digit month followed by a dash followed by a two digit day-of-month.

As such, the spec could have used `$year4-$month2-$day2`, which would equally well *define* the output format.

You will need to search and replace any input pattern to convert "Y" to "y" and "D" to "d".

I've also added some enhanced [documentation](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/key_format.html) of formatting.

Answer (score 4):

You're answer is in the docs: http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormat.html

The string format should be something like: "yyyy-MM-dd".

Comment: Thanks Jim.  I should have said that I did try the SimpleDateFormat style dates and could see that it worked fine for these.  I just thought that since joda-time docs state it supports ISO8601 formatted dates then I thought it would support them.  Not to worry... I'll figure something else out.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The date format described in [the w3 document](http://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime) and JodaTime's `DateTimeFormat` are different.

More specifically, in [`DateTimeFormat`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormat.html), the pattern `DD` is for `Day in year`, so the value for `DD` of `30` is the 30th day in the year, ie. January 30th. As the formatter is reading your date `String`, it sets the month to `07`. When it reads the day of year, it will overwrite that with `01` for January.

You need to use the pattern strings expected by `DateTimeFormat`, not the ones expected by the w3 dat and time formats. In this case, that would be

```
DateTimeFormatter dateDecoder = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd");
```